# What is an adjective for "that does not require a lot of energy/money/..."?

Tags: single-word-requests, word-choice, adjectives

I'm looking for somekind of antonym for "energy-intensive". I'm describing something that works well without using a lot of energy. I feel like the adjective I'm looking for also works for money.

Any ideas?

Comment: *Efficient* may well be your word.

Comment: I agree, it totally works, but I feel like there is another good match out there...

Comment: *Economic*, perhaps?

Comment: Might be a good match! Does it work with energy too? Sorry I still feel like I'm missing something better though. What about I formulate it as "something/someone which spares money/energy"? Do you see any other adjective?

Comment: Sparing, frugal, thrifty...

Comment: I think parsimonious is the exact one I was looking. I found it by looking sparing synonyms, thank you so much!

Comment: laid-back? (Hip, hip hooray for Esperanto! - to meet the minimum character-count requirement)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Single adjective meaning does not use much energy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/359820/single-adjective-meaning-does-not-use-much-energy/359830#359830) and  [What's a word that means "cost-effective" in the monetary context?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/113358/whats-a-word-that-means-cost-effective-in-the-monetary-context)

Comment: Parsimonious has strong connotations of being cheap or miserly, although doing so in a sensible manner.  A parsimonious person might do things like save spare screws to reuse for free in the future, or count each napkin they handed out to their restauraunt patrons.  Less about efficient use and more about careful use, IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest *economical*, as it can relate to money, time, or energy.

Defintion:

> Economical: giving good value or service in relation to the amount of **money, time, or effort** spent.
>   "a small, economical car"
>   synonyms:   cheap, inexpensive, low-cost, budget, economy, economic;

I also tend to think of "economic" as being more related to money or business than "economical," which is why I wouldn't suggest "economic" in your case.